# Can't seem to find DDMS in Android Studio 2.1.2

Tags: android-studio, dalvik, ddms

Not sure what I'm doing wrong here.

My basic goal is that I'd like to be able to take screenshots of my Android tablet via Android Studio which is running on my Windows laptop.

I gather I need Dalvik Debug Monitor Server (DDMS) to do this, however I'm struggling to find it within Android Studio.

All the guides I've read so far mention that you simply click on the DDMS menu button in the toolbar. This seems to appear like a green android robot.

Well, I have the android robot and so I click on that. The tooltip for the button says 'Android Device Monitor', nothing to do with DDMS.

And then normally says 'Android Monitor is already running' and does nothing. But all I have on my screen is Logcat and Monitors tab. I can't see the same stuff that I usually see on DDMS screenshots.

Occasionally it will throw an error which appears in the log files (but too big to post here)

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, officially dumb.

The DDMS was opening up in the background of another monitor.

Carry on...